# Use number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch as date format in logging

Tags: python, logging, time, epoch

The docs for [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) say:

> `datefmt` - Use the specified date/time format, as accepted by [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime).

However, if I have a look at the docs for [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime), the UNIX Epoch timestamp isn't even mentioned there.

---

**Update:** If I'm using `%s` as described in the manpage for [`strftime(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html), it works with Linux, but not with Windows.

```
import time
time.strftime('%s')
```

results in

```
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

So I'm looking for a platform-independent way to use the number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch as date format in logging.

Comment: `time.time()` _Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number_.  BTW, use _**Capital** Letter **S**_ in  `time.strftime('%S')`

Comment: The [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) function _in Python_ doesn't support the lowercase `%s` format directive (and the capitalized `%S` isn't the kind of seconds you want).

Comment: As mentioned in the docs: "Additional directives may be supported on certain platforms, but only the ones listed here have a meaning standardized by ANSI C" — which I believe is a long-winded way of saying "likely platform independent".

Comment: It's because internally it's implemented using a C runtime library for whatever the target platform was. This approach allows one to use platform-specific formatting if desired, but if you want maximum portability, you need to stick to what's in the ANSI C standard. I'm no logging expert, but it wouldn't surprise me if there's some way to do what you want though it.

Comment: @finefoot: Because reimplementing `strftime` would be expensive, incompatible to the same degree with other programs on the same platform, and likely in corner cases to exhibit different behavior from those other programs.  Anyone who thinks `%s` should be part of C, or of Windows’ implementation thereof, can talk to WG14 or to Microsoft respectively; such changes are less impossible than they might seem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with `asctime` for certain, since the behavior of `strftime` regarding supported format strings is platform-dependent.

There is a paragraph in the docs in the section "`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior" about this:

> The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s `strftime()` function, and platform variations are common. To see the full set of format codes supported on your platform, consult the *strftime(3)* documentation.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

---

However, disregarding `asctime`, you can still use the number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch in your logginng format string. There is another attribute called `created`:

> `%(created)f` - Time when the LogRecord was created (as returned by `time.time()`).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Since `time.time()` works on both Linux and Windows, you can just use `created` instead of `asctime` in the logging format string.

Answer (score 1):

The Unix epoch format cannot be obtained using `strftime()` in ANSI C (afterall, that is kind of the input).
Similarly, you cannot have this functionality as cross-platform in Python.

However, you can take advantage of the fact that non-special characters pass through `strftime()` both in C and in Python.
Therefore, you could use the following -- admittedly quite ugly but effective -- workaround:

```py
import time

time.strftime(str(time.time()))
```

or more precisely:

```py
time.strftime(str(int(time.time())))

time.strftime(str(int(time.time()))) == time.strftime('%s')
# True
```